# Ok() doesn't exist in current context unless async is used

Tags: c#, .net, controller

I'm not sure why this is happening but in the code I am showing below, it is saying that 'Ok' doesn't exist in this current context but when I add async to the code, the error goes away and it works again. I dont put an await or anything, it's just the async. The working one gives a warning, like it should but for some reason it is making it work, does anyone know why, and how do I fix this?

Not working:

```
    public Task<IActionResult> GetBusinesses()
    {
        var events = _context.Businesses.Include(p => p.Locations).ToList();

        return Ok(events);
    }
```

Working:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetBusinesses()
    {
        var events = _context.Businesses.Include(p => p.Locations).ToList();

        return Ok(events);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok() returns an IActionResult and not a Task. Either add the async or remove the Task.